# load data from csv file to table by specific columns

Tags: mysql, mysql++

I'm using mysql++ to insert data to table from csv file

```
    mysqlpp::Query insert_query = conn.query("load data local infile 'm_variation_bunrui.csv' INTO TABLE m_variation_bunrui FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';");
    cout <<"Query 1:"<<  insert_query <<endl;
    mysqlpp::SimpleResult res = insert_query.execute();
    cout << res.info() <<endl;
    cout << insert_query.error() <<endl;
```

But it just say :

```
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 9
```

I show created table but have no expected data
What wrong with my program ?

//Update :

I checked  the command in mysql cmd ,it won't work as expect ,so that I fixed it :

```
load data local infile '/path/to/mycsv.csv' CHARACTER SET 'sjis' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' INTO TABLE m_variation_bunrui(colum1,colum2) ;
```

and check again in mysql cmd:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET 'sjis' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' INTO TABL' at line 1
```

Please help me to correct it

Comment: I'm not a C++ expert, but have you tried executing the raw query in MySQL?  If it also doesn't work there, then the problem might have nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Tim is right you should check the query on the client first; MySQL has a strange rule about permissions so when you GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES to a user you find out that ALL does not include the FILE privilege which is necessary to import a CSV but not to create a new table.

Comment: thank ,the problem is my sql query , please help me to check it